# Run node.js database migrations on Google Cloud SQL during Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

I would like to run database migrations written in node.js during the Cloud Build process.

Currently, the database migration command is being executed but it seems that the Cloud Build process does not have access to connect to Cloud SQL via an IP address with username/password.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the case with [**Cloud SQL**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) and **Node.js** it would look something like this:

```yaml
steps:
  # Install Node.js dependencies
  - id: yarn-install
    name: node:18
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["install", "--frozen-lockfile"]
    waitFor: ["-"]

  # Install Cloud SQL proxy
  - id: proxy-install
    name: node:18
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - "wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.4.0/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy && chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy"
    waitFor: ["-"]

  # Migrate database schema to the latest version
  - id: migrate
    name: node:18
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - "mkdir /cloudsql; chmod 777 /cloudsql; (./cloud_sql_proxy --unix-socket /cloudsql <CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION> & sleep 2) && yarn knex migrate:latest"
    timeout: "1200s"
    waitFor: ["yarn-install", "proxy-install"]
timeout: "1200s"
```

You would launch `yarn install` and download [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) in parallel. Once these two steps are complete, you run launch the proxy, wait 2 seconds and finally run `yarn knex migrate:latest`.

For this to work you would need [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sqladmin.googleapis.com) enabled in your GCP project.

Where `<CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE>` is your Cloud SQL instance connection name that can be found [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql). The same name will be used in your SQL connection settings, e.g. `host=/cloudsql/example:us-central1:pg13`.

Also, make sure that the Cloud Build service account has "Cloud SQL Client" role in the GCP project, where the db instance is located.

Comment: That looks perfect, cheers mate. I'll give it a go tonight and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Works well! The trick with this for those that didn't read Konstantin's summary is that the mounting of the Google Cloud SQL proxy and migration happens in an asynchronous fashion as once you launch the Cloud SQL proxy it stays open.

One thing to mention though, remember to add the Google Cloud SQL client IAM permission to the Google Cloud Build IAM service account.

Comment: Did you run into an issue with it not connecting to localhost? I'm getting an issue where it looks like the cloud sql proxy successfully connects, and it even says "Accepting connections on 127.0.0.1:5432", but when I try to connect, it says "ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432". This works perfectly on my local machine. They're both part of the same volume.

Comment: Not enough upvotes on SO! Note that for similar use cases like running django tests, you may need more than just a Cloud SQL Client role since tests can involve creating DBs.

Comment: Doesn't work with latest image gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy v1.16, due to switching to distroless image without shell. More info in official issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/317. For now you can use v1.15 or alternative approach: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/317#issuecomment-542847036

Comment: The documentation provides a direct non-versioned URL to download which might be worth using instead: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#install

Comment: This worked for me, but had some gcloud error which was resolved by bumping Cloud SQL Proxy to v1.20.2

Comment: timeout at end gives me syntax errors

Comment: Getting an error that gcloud is unavailable even with the newest proxy version.

Answer (score 12):

As of tag `1.16` of `gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy`, the currently accepted answer no longer works. Here is a different approach that keeps the proxy in the same step as the commands that need it:

```yaml
  - id: cmd-with-proxy
    name: [YOUR-CONTAINER-HERE]
    timeout: 100s
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - '(/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME] & sleep 2) && [YOUR-COMMAND-HERE]'
```

The proxy will automatically exit once the main process exits. Additionally, it'll mark the step as "ERROR" if either the proxy or the command given fails.

This does require the binary is in the `/workspace` volume, but this can be provided either manually or via a prereq step like this:

```yaml
  - id: proxy-install
    name: alpine:3.10
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - 'wget -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy https://storage.googleapis.com/cloudsql-proxy/v1.16/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.386 &&  chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy'
```

Additionally, this should work with TCP since the proxy will be in the same container as the command.

Comment: Cloud SQL Proxy v2 changes the arguments so that this example would instead be `'(/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME & sleep 2) && [YOUR-COMMAND-HERE]'`, otherwise the steps remain the same and work as described.

Answer (score 3):

Use [google-appengine/exec-wrapper](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/tree/master/app-engine-exec-wrapper). It is an image to do exactly this. Usage (see README in link):

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
  args: ["-i", "gcr.io/my-project/appengine/some-long-name",
         "-e", "ENV_VARIABLE_1=value1", "-e", "ENV_2=value2",
         "-s", "my-project:us-central1:my_cloudsql_instance",
         "--", "bundle", "exec", "rake", "db:migrate"]
```

The `-s` sets the proxy target.

Comment: If you are running a script inside the inner container specified in "-i" argument. What would the host be for the nested inner container. 127.0.0.1 does not seem to work. I am attempting to run a flyway container within the exec-wrapper container using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Build runs using a service account and it looks like you need to grant access to Cloud SQL for this account. 
You can find additional info about setting service account permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions).

Comment: I tried something along the lines of this, adding the Cloud SQL role to the Cloud Build IAM. Didn't have much luck.

Comment: Did you try to run build locally? https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally. It runs under your account and if it will work correctly - problems with permissions, if not - problem somewhere else.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. Ill give that a go shortly, an easier way to debug for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to combine Cloud Build + Cloud SQL Proxy + Docker.

If you're running your database migrations/operations within a Docker container in Cloud Build, it won't be able to directly access your proxy, because Docker containers are isolated from the host machine.

Here's what I managed to get up and running:

```yaml
  - id: build
    # Build your application
    waitFor: ['-']

  - id: install-proxy
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - wget -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy https://storage.googleapis.com/cloudsql-proxy/v1.15/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.386 && chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy
    waitFor: ['-']

  - id: migrate
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances=projectid:region:instanceid & sleep 2 && \
        docker run -v /workspace:/root \
        --env DATABASE_HOST=/root/projectid:region:instanceid \
        # Pass other necessary env variables like db username/password, etc.
        $_IMAGE_URL:$COMMIT_SHA
    timeout: '1200s'
    waitFor: [build, install-proxy]
```

Because our db operations are taking place within the Docker container, I found the best way to provide the access to Cloud SQL by specifying the Unix socket `-dir/workspace` instead of exposing a TCP port 5432.

*Note: I recommend using the directory `/workspace` instead of `/cloudsql` for Cloud Build.*

Then we mounted the `/workspace` directory to Docker container's `/root` directory, which is the default directory where your application code resides. When I tried to mount it to other than `/root`, nothing seemed to happen (perhaps a permission issue with no error output).

Also: I noticed the proxy version 1.15 works well. I had issues with newer versions. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I spent some days trying to make this work... As you say, when copied to root it magically works - otherwise, it doesn't. Thanks for your tip ... I wish I knew why that is.

Answer (score 1):

here is my updated solution for 2024, based on Konstantin's one :

```
- id: install-proxy
name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget'
entrypoint: bash
args:
  - "-c"
  - "wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.8.1/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy && chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy"

- id: migrate
    waitFor: ['install-proxy']
    name: '<YOUR IMAGE>'
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - "(./cloud_sql_proxy --address <DB_HOST> --port <DB_PORT> <PROJECT_ID>:<REGION>:<DB_INSTANCE> & sleep 2) && cd <YOUR SCRIPT FOLDER> && <YOUR MIGRATION SCRIPT>"
    timeout: '1200s'
```