# Is there a way to allow cloudbuild steps to access the Cloud SQL in GCP

Tags: docker, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

I'm setting up a cloud build trigger in order to deploy a PHP/Symfony Application. When the docker file runs the `php app/console assetic:dump` command in order to create the assets I get the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out 
[PDOException] 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] 


An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
Connection timed out 
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
```

I have resolved to trying to get the docker container to connect to the database instead of trying to fix the symfony application because I don't know enough about the framework or php.

Is it possible to set this up so that I can allow some kind of IP on the CLOUDSQL side to allow these connections?

Comment: I saw in another SO post, you can use an extra build step to run the cloud sql proxy and connect that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52366671
But I'm also hoping a simpler solution is possible...

Comment: Did the solution provided by chmod_007 work for you?

Comment: @alextru I have yet to be able to try it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to setup the proxy in the same step is described in the answer here:

[Run node.js database migrations on Google Cloud SQL during Google Cloud Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352103/run-node-js-database-migrations-on-google-cloud-sql-during-google-cloud-build/64599510#64599510)