# How do I install mysql and run script in cloud build?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm starting to use Cloud Build for a project, and I'm having the following issue:
Using this cloudbuild.yaml file:

```yml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['test']
```

The build run okay on the first step because it is able to install the dependencies and everything but in the second step it fails because it needs to connect to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52366671), you can use an extra build step to run the Cloud SQL proxy and connect that way. Check it out that let us know if that solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Michael T I will check and try it out.

Comment: Hi, yes that solution works having an instance of Cloud SQL, but it doesn't make too much sense for development to have an instance and incurs on costs.  Will be really useful if I could have a build step that says just install MySql with these parameters - run the following script and then run the tests. But I think Cloud build is mostly for deployment than for running integration tests and unit tests like other tools (Travis, Soucelabs, etc)

Comment: Glad to hear that works. I understand that having an instance of CloudSQL isn’t the expected way to make it work, but it is the proper way to make it work. There may be other 'workarounds' that are not entirely supported and can cause issues on future builds.