# Running database migrations during Google Cloud Build fails with ENOTFOUND error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I am trying to run migrations through Sequelize in Node JS on Google Cloud Run connecting to a MySQL Google Cloud SQL database. I followed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58441728/4487248 to get the Google Cloud proxy setup. Given this log setting up the proxy connection to the database seems to have worked:

```log
Step #2 - "migrate": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
Step #2 - "migrate": 2021/10/02 14:19:58 current FDs rlimit set to 1048576, wanted limit is 8500. Nothing to do here.
Step #2 - "migrate": 2021/10/02 14:19:58 Listening on /workspace/<MY-INSTANCE-NAME> for <MY-INSTANCE-NAME>
Step #2 - "migrate": 2021/10/02 14:19:58 Ready for new connections
Step #2 - "migrate": 2021/10/02 14:19:58 Generated RSA key in 74.706896ms
```

However, when I try to run migrations with `yarn knex migrate:latest` or `./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` I run into:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND /workspace/<MY-INSTANCE-NAME>
```

This seems to imply that the host could not be found.

---

### Output / Logs

My `cloudbuild.yaml` (composed of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52366671/4487248 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/58441728/4487248):

```yaml
steps:
  # Install Node.js dependencies
  - id: yarn-install
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
    waitFor: ["-"]

  # Install Cloud SQL proxy
  - id: proxy-install
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - "wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cloudsql-proxy/v1.25.0/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy && chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy"
    waitFor: ["-"]

  - id: migrate
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - "(/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances=<MY-INSTANCE-NAME> & sleep 2) && ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate"
    timeout: "1200s"
    waitFor: ["yarn-install", "proxy-install"]

timeout: "1200s"
```

My `.sequelizerc` (Documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#dynamic-configuration)):

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
}
```

My `config/config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  production: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: `/workspace/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`, // Replacing this line with `/workspace/cloudsql/${..}` or `/cloudsql/${..}` leads to the same error
    dialect: 'mysql',
  }
}
```

I did enable Public IP on the MySQL instance:
[image: MySQL Instance]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the host to `localhost` and adding the instance path in `socketPath` in `config.js` fixed the issue:

```
module.exports = {
  production: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: localhost,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
      socketPath: `/workspace/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
    },
  }
}
```